# VisualStudio 2017 Lightweight mode can't be turned off

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2017

I turned off lightweight for solution in`VS2017`, in **Tools->Options->ProjectsAndSolutions->General**,
[image]

But projects is loading in `lazy` mode (only when i clicked on the project):
[image]

Also i clicked `disable light weight solution load mode` in the solution context and it doesn't help.

It is hard to work in `VS` with such bug, because i need to open all 62 projects manually to start working/. Without these 62 steps, code editor thinks that interfces and classes declared in uloaded projects do not exist.

How to turn  off the 'lightweight' mode?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on solution, go for “**Disable Lightweight Solution Load**” context menu option and then re-open the solution.